# Can I write Java/.Net/JavaScript/NodeJS developer job title as Software Developer?

Tags: title

When I am applying for a new job, I often see some position's job title as Java or .Net or JavaScript or NodeJS developer. If I am hired as one of above titles, can I write job title as Software Developer? The reason why I ask is that I think the Software Developer term seems broader. Shouldn't it be easier to pass the resume screening and find a new job?

Comment: Title's differ from organization to organization. One company might have a program director doing the same thing as the program coordinator at another. Therefore keep the title you are hired under and describe what you do in your resume.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking "Is it ethical to change my job title (as given by the company) to a more universally understood title on my resume."

That would be a yes. If your goal is to pass screenings, **ideally you'll find a way to list both.**

**Example**

> **Software Developer, Inicorp, July 2016 - current**
>
> As the senior *NodeJS developer* in the XYZ team at Inicorp, ... #Mentoring #Coaching #Teamplayer

or another one where an alternate title can be necessary:

> **Project Manager, Inicorp, July 2016 - current**
>
> As *Scrum Master* of the XYZ team at Inicorp, ... #Agile

Comment: Interesting how you put "scrum master" under "project manager". It's a bit off-topic to ask (as it's only an example in an answer), but do you have any resources that could explain this? The way I view these two titles personally are very different from each other, but I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I chose this example specifically because the Scrum Master title is familiar to many readers of this site, a very ambiguous title, and is simply not understood at all at many companies that don't practice Scrum. Of course the role also isn't understood well at many companies that claim to practice Scrum, but that's another can of worms - and the source of the title's ambiguity. Project Manager accurately describes some Scrum Masters, but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

1. No one on Earth will have either the intention or the ability to track back your original job tender which you've applied to.
2. Employed as "JavaScript/Java/Anything Developer" doesn't mean, that you won't do any different there. Although the majority of your tasks will be likely the named technologies.
3. Also this is likely that the company in a following project will give you a task with a different technology, as firing you and get another developer (assuming that they are satisfied with your work).

In your CV, what is important in the future, *what you actually worked on*, not your - theoretical - initial job title.

In your CV, you will have roughly this entry:

> Company X, 2013-2016, Senior Software Developer
>
> JavaScript, Java, Angular, PostgreSQL

...or some similar. The details depend on the detailedness of your CV (and on the customs of your country).